# Why is my Sum algorithm stuck in a loop/Taking a very long time?

Tags: python

I'm new to the world of algorithms and have attempted to write my own after studying a few. I'm trying to find if the sum of two numbers in an array sum up to a target value. The issue is that it loops continuously and I would be extremely grateful for some help as i just cant seem to see what it is.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,4]
target = 8

def findSum(arr, target):

  if len(arr) <= 1:
    return False
  low = 0
  high = len(arr) - 1

  while low <= high:
    for i in range(low, high):
      for j in range(high, low, -1):
        if (arr[i]+arr[j]) == target:
          return(arr[i], arr[j])
        elif (arr[i]+arr[j]) > target:
          high -= 1
        else:
          low += 1
  return False

findSum(arr, target)
```

P.S Sorry about the uncommented code, I didn't think it was necessary with the simplicity of it.

Comment: You have no breaks in your while loop which would run continuously until all conditions don't work. Also it isn't so simple. Are you okay with 1 pair of numbers adding up to your target or do you want all pairs that add up to the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it incorrectly,
You might want to try this,

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,4]
target = 8

def findSum(arr, target):
    start = 0
    end = len(arr) - 1

    while start < end:
        if arr[start] + arr[end] == target:
            return (arr[start], arr[end])
        elif arr[start] + arr[end] < target:
            start += 1
        else:
            end -= 1

    return False

print(findSum(arr, target))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
(4, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is **any** two elements that sum up to the target value, this is much simpler version:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,4]
target = 8

def findSum(arr, target):
  for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
      if (arr[i]+arr[j]) == target and i != j:
        return(arr[i], arr[j])
  return False

print(findSum(arr, target))
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code:
This is your outer loop

```
for i in range(low, high):
```

This is your inner loop

```
for j in range(high, low, -1):
```

While the outer loop is still at i==0, the inner loop has run len(arr) times, increasing the low from 0 to 4. 
Then it will stuck there. Because low == high == 4, it will not leave the while loop, nor run the range.